# How to change the interpreter of the project

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I created a django project and its interpreter is an 3.5.2 ENV, all the extensions that I install in Pycharm it doesn't recognize them, when I try to add them in Installed APPS, they aren't available.

But if the interpreter is only python.exe it recognizes.

So, How do I change the intrepeter of a project that is set to the 3.5 2 ENV to another, I don't know exatly what ENV is, and why it doesn't allow me to use installed extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `preferences` then `project`. You can set the interpreter there.[image]

Comment: I did it, but it didn't work as I wanted, in the external Libraries the old interpreter is still there, and I can't use the installed extensions

Comment: Sorry I had done it wrong, it worked, thank you very much friend

Answer (score 1):

I assume the ENV you are talking about is a virtual environment. You normally create your project inside a virtual environment in order to maintain project-specific dependencies. E.g. If you install a dependency in your virtual environment, it can be accessed ONLY from that container. So, it is not installed system-wide and therefore cannot be accessed by things outside of the ENV.

Makes sense because you don't really want to install project specific things system-wide. E.g. what if you wanted to work on one project with Django 1.10 and another with 1.8? You would create two virtualenvs to encapsulate each!

I know it doesn't answer your main question but it may help to understand what's going on.

https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/

Comment: Yes it is a virtual environment, I don't know why when I install some app with the PIP, the project inside a virtual environment doesn't recognize the app, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Did you activate the virtualenv before doing your pip installs? You need to navigate to your env folder from your command shell and do a 'source bin/activate'. THEN do pip install stuff